# Member not found error in java script

Tags: javascript

The below code for opening and closing a window is throwing a java script error 'Member not found'. This does not happen in all machines but for certain users with IE 8. 
winobject.blur() in the following code is throwing the error.

```
var winobject=null;   
winobject = window.open('URL','Name',"width=1,height=1,top=2000,left=2000");
if(winobject!=null){
    winobject.blur();
    self.resizeTo(screen.availWidth,screen.availHeight);
    winobject.close();
    ...
}
```

Any help or suggestion to resolve this issue?

Some additional observations- This issue only occurs when a window with the 'Name' already exists. Lets say if the user has already closed the pop up window that was already opened then the code will run fine. Also if I add one more window.open under the current one then no exception gets thrown when blur() is invoked. Not sure why though ?

Comment: What does `self` refer to, in your code? Current window? Are you sure `winobject.blur()` is throwing the error after trying Tomasz's suggestion?

Comment: @OnurYILDIRIM - yes, self refer to the current window.. I had a try catch block over the new code and was still getting the exception. ty

Answer (score 1):

<strike>`if (typeof winobject != "undefined")`</strike>

I just had an issue with something like this at work today. give that a try, you should be good to go.

Edit:

I have found [the following link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/973528) which appears to explain what is going on. Because you are creating that `window` on your own, IE8's "security" is preventing many common actions on it.

My next suggestion as a workaround would be to surround both the `winobject.blur()` and `winobject.close()` with `if (winobject.blur)` and `if (winobject.close())` conditionals. Note that you do not have the parenthesis after `blur` and `close` in the `if`'s, as you are looking for the presence of the method as opposed to calling the method.

Unfortunately, I'm not sure what the alternatives are that you can use to obtain the same effect. But that should hopefully prevent the error from being thrown.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The suggested approach is not working for me :(

Comment: Thanks for the additional information; it really helped. I tried out every thing suggested so far but was unable to resolve the issue...

Comment: There's always `if (browser == 'InternetExplorer') window.redirect('http://chrome.com/download');` Sorry you still can't get it to work. I'll take a look and see if I can find anything else when I get home tonight.

Comment: Check out this link about the focusin and focusout. They do bubble, but you should be able to work around that (iirc).

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/blurfocus.html